# Compilation error sequence: Static compilation error coming after resolving access modifier error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

In the below piece of code:

```
public class ModifierNotAllowInMethodCheck {

    private int pvtInt;

    public static void method1() {
        System.out.println("pvtInt = " + pvtInt);
        int var1 = 10;
        System.out.println("var1 = " + var1);
        public int var2 = 20;
        System.out.println("var2 = " + var2);
    } // end of method1()

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        method1();
    } // end of main()

} // end of class
```

When compiled, the statement

`public int var2 = 20;`

would come as the first compilation error and then the statement

`System.out.println("pvtInt = " + pvtInt);`

would come as the compilation error, once I resolve the first one.

Q - Why doesn't the static variable reference compilation error come first?

Comment: Variables inside a method can't have access modifiers.

Comment: I think they are asking why the order of the errors happened the way they did, not why are the errors happening.. That's the way I understood it.

Comment: Is `public int var1` supposed to be `public int var2` ?

Comment: @Devon thanks, edited.

Comment: @Powerlord yes, you're right. That's what I was checking, however, my confusion is in the sequence in which I get the compilation errors. I was expecting the static reference error to come first when compiled and then the error for using modifier inside the method, but it's coming the other way round.

Comment: @LokeshwarTailor, May I know how you are compiling your code. Is it using command line? Because it eclipse I can see static reference error coming first and the other as next.

Comment: @SantosshKumhar Yes, I am using CLI to compile my code

Comment: I got the same result when I tested the code as you. I'm not sure why it errors out in that order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thing is: you **assume** that compiler gives errors in the order they appear in source code. But that isn't how compilers work.

Of course, when you have 5 errors of the same kind, you can expect that you get them in the order of line numbers.

But when you have different *categories*, then the compiler can decide what category to worry about first. And you see: identifying **wrong** modifiers within methods is something that can be done much easier, compared to looking at variables and scoping.

And note: having access modifiers *within* method bodies, that is a *syntax* problem. It makes sense that pure *syntax* problems are found and reported first. The `pvInt` thing is more complicated, that is about semantics! The compiler needs to fully know the (static) fields of the class before it can do that checking.

Comment: I completely agree with your insights. Just to re-frame, _the sequence of compilation errors can occur based on its categorization._ However, from a beginner's perspective, it would be a bit harder in pin-pointing the intended behavior.
Looking for any official references for the same. Do share if you come across (assuming your insights come from experience)